# Installer stuck on 'Updates and other software' when dual booting Ubuntu 20.04 alongside Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, uefi, windows-10

I am trying to dual boot my PC with Ubuntu 20.04 alongside Windows 10, following steps like those described [here](https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/), however my installer keeps getting stuck on the 'Updates and other software' screen (the screen showed [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f10xh.jpg)).

My installation process is the following:

- Create bootable Ubuntu 20.04 *.iso* image using [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/en/).
- Partition SSD to allocate space (250GB) for Ubuntu.
- Boot Ubuntu from USB drive.
- Choose 'Try Live' option.
- Make */home/* and */root/* partitions on the allocated space.
- Execute the 'Install Ubuntu 20.04' that sits on the desktop.

I am almost certain it remains stuck, as I've let it run for upwards of 4 hours without any progress.

This appears to be a common problem, as many have reported similar hang-ups occurring during the installation process (as seen [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1766978), [here](https://appuals.com/how-to-fix-ubuntu-20-04-installer-stuck-at-updates/), and [here](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/installation-hangs-on-software-updates-page/22152/2). However, none of the solutions provided to their problems have worked for me. For example, I cannot mount/unmount Windows-related partitions and no needed partition appears to be corrupted.

I have tried the following:

- Disable Windows hibernation
- Doing the installation in a *safe graphics* boot of Ubuntu
- Choosing *minimal installation* as to not download many updates for Ubuntu

But the problem remains. My biggest issue is that I am not sure if the installer is just incredibly slow, or if it is really stuck, as I have no insight to what it is currently doing. Therefore, my question is twofold:

1. Is there some way to know what the installer is currently doing? Or, can I find out what command is currently being executed by the installer that causes the hang-up?
2. How can I install Ubuntu 20.04 alongside Windows 10 without the installer hanging up?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Also, if more information/specifics are needed, I can of course provide these.

System specifics:

- CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 2600 Six-core Processor
- GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660 SUPER
- Motherboard: Gigabyte B450M DS3H

Comment: `my installer keeps getting stuck on the 'Updates and other software' screen (as seen here).` -- The link on "here" does not work

Comment: Fixed the broken link for the screenshot of the installer.

Comment: Have you verified the checksum of the written usb stick? Have you tried using another program to make your installation usb stick (Balena Etcher, Ventoy, Unetbootin, Universal-USB-Installer)? Did you disable 'secure boot'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: remove internet access.

Even though I selected a minimal install without downloading additional updates, when I disconnected my internet the installer did not halt on 'Updates and other software'.
I am still, however, unsure what causes the installer to hang-up when connected to the internet.